# How to Inject existing PDO object to doctrine entity manager

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to create a PHP package using doctrine entity manager.

This package will be used in different projects in my company, and some projects are not using doctrine, but a PDO connection.

I want to be able to instantiate a doctrine entity manager in my package with an existing stand-alone PDO object, because I don't want (and I just can't) to create another DB connection. I have to use the existing one.

Is that a way to do that? Something like:

```php
$em = EntityManager::createWithPDOInstance($pdoObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the solution by myself.

I post the code, it may help someone in the future.

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Factory;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

class EntityManagerFactory
{
    /**
     * @param \PDO $pdo
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function create(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $config = new Configuration();
        $config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/EntityProxy');
        $config->setProxyNamespace('EntityProxy');
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);

        AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');

        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(new AnnotationDriver(
            new AnnotationReader(),
            array(__DIR__ . '/')
        ));

        return EntityManager::create(
            DriverManager::getConnection(
                [
                    'driver' => 'pdo_' . $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME),
                    'pdo' => $pdo,
                ],
                $config),
            $config
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your approach, and worked for the most part. The problem I had is that my entities had also JmsSerializer annotations. And when I tried to find an entity it was throwing an exception that the JmsSerializer annotation wasn't recognized.

To fix it, I changed the `AnnotationRegistry::registerFile` for 
`AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');` and that fixed my errors